# woocommerce_created_customer action not working at all

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am writing plugin which sends coupon code for every X spent at shop and this feature works pretty well but I have troubles with sending coupon to a new registered user. 
Sending mail function (XYZ here on purpose):

```
function sendFirstVoucher($to_email, $discount, $name,  $coupon){
    $headers = 'From: XYZ' . "";
    $subject = 'Your ' . $discount . '% discount voucher for XYZ';
    $message = 'Hi . ' . $name . 'and thank you for registering with XYZ! \r\n\r\n' . 
            "blah blah blah " . $coupon . " when you check out on our website, you can apply the code in either the cart page or check out page. \r\n\r\n" . 
            "From now on when you make purchases you will also receive additional discount codes for every $100 spent. More information can be found at our website (link to membership program page). \r\n" .
            "If you have any questions please feel free to contact us at XYZ \r\n\r\n" . 
            "Kind Regards, \r\nThe XYZ";
    wp_mail($to_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

And in the main plugin file:

```
function send_coupon_to_freshly_registered_user($customer_id, $new_customer_data, $password_generated) {
        $coupon_code = generateCoupon(5);
        $user_email = $new_customer_data["user_email"];
        $user_login = $new_customer_data["user_login"];
        sendFirstVoucher($user_email, "5", $user_login, $coupon_code);
    }
```

finally at the nearly end of file there is:

```
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'send_coupon_to_freshly_registered_user',10,3);
```

But once I am creating user via dashboard or register myself via wp-login page (because site is in maintenace mode) it's not sending any email nor creating coupon (it works perfectly for similar function for X voucher per 100$)

Have anyone got idea how to acomplish this?

Kind regards,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have achieved this by using core wp functions:

```
add_action('user_register', 'send_coupon_to_freshly_registered_user',10,1);
function send_coupon_to_freshly_registered_user($user_id) {
        $user = get_user_by('id',$user_id); //new line
        $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login); //changed line
        $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email); //changed line
        $coupon_code = generateCoupon(5);
        sendFirstVoucher($user_email, "5", $user_login, $coupon_code);
}
```

I hope it will help someone. Maybe it's not a real answer but the one that works for me.

Regards, 
Tom